# Setting an attribute on_create - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have an attribute called `Subscribed_date` but right now it's nil after a person subscribes. That makes sense considering that no logic is interacting with the attribute. However, I don't want this attribute to set the date only on subscription but also on renewal. So needs are this - 1. Every time a user subscribes they subscribed for exactly one year.
2. So this attribute would set when they subscribe and reset when they renew after the year is up.

Basically it needs to be dynamic and not just set to the created_at attribute, I guess I'm struggling understanding how to do this. Any help would be great.

### CONTROLLER:

```
 class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @search = Subscriber.search(params[:q])
    @subscriber = @search.result
    @search.build_condition if @search.conditions.empty?
    @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?
  end

  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

### schema:

```
   create_table "Subscribers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.integer  "visit"
    t.integer  "mug_number"
    t.date     "subscription_date"
  end
```

### MODEL:

```
  class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_mug_number

  scope :subscribing, -> {where subscription_date > 1.year.ago}
  scope :non_subscribing, -> {where.not subscription_date > 1.year.ago}

  has_many :comments
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_PHONE_REGEX = /\d{10}/
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :phone_number, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :numericality => true, :format => VALID_PHONE_REGEX

  def date_joined
    created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
  end

  def expiration_date
    (created_at + 1.year).strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
  end

  def days_till_expired
    ((created_at + 1.year) - DateTime.now).to_i / 1.day
  end

  def subscribing?
    subscription_date > 1.year.ago
  end

  private

  def generate_mug_number
    last_number = Subscriber.maximum(:mug_number) || 0
    self.mug_number = last_number + 1
  end
end
```

As you can see everything is pretty basic. Let me know if you need more info. Thank You!

Comment: When a new subscriber is created you want to set its date with current date?

Comment: @Kumar, Yea, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do like this.

```
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params) # create method will directly save it, so you're checking if @subcriber.save for nothing
  # I've changed it to new
  if @subscriber.save
    #if the record is saved successfully, it next we'll update the time
    @subscriber.touch(:subscription_date) #this will update and save it.
    flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
    redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Similarly, you can do a `touch` on your renew action, that will store the current date of the day when renewed and update it.

Comment: Thanks @kumar! However, I'm getting an error that say `cannot touch on a new record object`. Any idea on what's that is about

Comment: Right, you need to save it first. So I guess what you did would be the right thing. Updating my codes in a minute.